# Verificação de e-mail antes do envio

Tags: wordpress

Tenho a seguinte página http://neilgaiman.com.br/contato/ para contato de um site.
As vezes, as pessoas digitam o campo **e-mail** errado, e isso me impede de respondê-lá.
Existe como haver uma verificação desse campo, para confirmar a existência desse e-mail?

Pode ser plugin, pois utilizo Wordpress.

Comment: Não tem como ter certeza que um email existe ou não, no máximo testar se tem uma arroba e um ponto ao menos depois da arroba. Praticamente qualquer teste a mais vai atrapalhar possíveis emails válidos (está cheio de formulário e tutorial pela web que ensina validar de maneira errada). Além disso, sem enviar alguma coisa, definitivamente não vai saber se o email existe. Dá até pra usar dois campos do tipo senha obrigando o usuário a digitar duas vezes se for realmente importante, mas fica um pouco estranho.

Comment: Estava pensando em criar um novo campo de confirmação de e-mail.
De qualquer forma, não tem como fazer algo, que envie algum teste e retorne? Tipo esse site http://verify-email.org/

Comment: Esses testes se baseiam no servidor da outra parte "dedurar" se a conta existe ou não. O problema é que em algumas situações, o servidor aceita qq coisa e descarta depois. Além disso, se o domínio em questão tiver uma conta "papa tudo", você vai ter um email válido, porém pode estar indo para a pessoa errada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode se conectar ao servidor, e emitir um comando VRFY. Muito poucos servidores suportam este comando, mas destina-se exatamente isso. Se o servidor responde com um DSN 2.0.0, existe o usuário.

```
VRFY user
```

Você pode emitir um RCPT, e ver se o e-mail é rejeitado.

```
MAIL FROM:<>

RCPT TO:<user@domain>
```

Se o usuário não existir, você vai ter um DSN 5.1.1. Entretanto, apenas porque o e-mail não é rejeitada, não significa que o usuário existe. Alguns servidor irá silenciosamente descartar pedidos como este para evitar a enumeração de seus usuários. Outros servidores não podem verificar o usuário, e tem que aceitar a mensagem independentemente.

Comment: O problema é que este recurso só estará ativo em servidores "mau configurados", pois por motivos de segurança esta é a primeira coisa que se desabilita num servidor de emails.

Comment: exatamente concordo com você @NilsonUehara mas foi a forma mais simples que encontrei para isto

Answer (score -1):

A resposta do @Otto é show; é bom verificar se a conta existe. Acho a verificação com expressão regular incompleta/insuficiente, apesar de muito utilizada.

Uma das validações que uso é:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

[Testador de expressões regulares](http://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php)

Essa validação é portanto simples. Ela casa [qualquerString]@[qualquerString].[qualquerString]

Comment: Então, essa expressão verifica o formato do e-mail, isso? Show de bola, esse teste o plugin Contact Form 7 que uso já faz, eu precisaria é testar o domínio mesmo.